# Upgrading .net core 2.2 console app to .net core 3.0. 3.0 unavailable

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a solution that contains a console project, library project and test project.  when I try to update the framework to 3.0 that option is not available however I have another console project that I can select that option from and I can also create a new 3.0 project

I have upgraded visual studio and installed the sdk.  I have verified from the console that the 3.0.100 sdk is there.

When I try to update my project to 3.0 that option is not available.  If I update the project manually I get: Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NETSDK1045  The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0. FileMover.Core  C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets   137

Answer (score 0):

global.json was my enemy.  this has been resolved by updating the json file